# Django Models - Prepare the data for the database

Tags: django, django-models

I have a form that askes for a phone number.  I need to make sure that only digits [0-9] get saved in the database.

In the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/)  it says:

What happens when you save?

3) Prepare the data for the database. Each field is asked to provide its current value in a data type that can be written to the database.

How does this happen?  Or more specifically, how can I make sure this is cleaned?  I know that I can just override the models save method, but it seems like there is a better way and I'm just not sure how to do it.

I guess I could write a custom field for it, but that seems like overkill here.

Also, I realize that I can put the validation on the form, but it really feels like stripping out the characters belongs on the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question specifically about point 3 is a little different from "cleaning" in the way django uses the term.

> 3) Prepare the data for the database. Each field is asked to provide its current value in a data type that can be written to the database.

Point 3 is about converting the python object values to one suitable for a database. Specifically, this is done in `Field.get_prep_value` and `Field.get_db_prep_value`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.get_prep_value

It's the opposite of `to_python` which takes a DB value and converts it to a python object.

As for ensuring only digits 0-9 get stored, that would be done in a `Field`s `clean` method (subclass IntegerField), form `clean` method, form `clean_FIELDNAME` method, or model `clean`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom Form Cleaning method to your objects model - take a look at this article https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning

Look at "Cleaning a specific field attribute"

Answer (score 0):

use [django model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) + [custom form field cleaning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)

Below is a quick example of what you might be looking for, where `MyModel` is the model containing the phone number field, which I named it `tel` here.

```
import re

class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def clean_tel(self):
        tel = self.cleaned_data.get('tel', '')  # this is from user input

        # use regular expression to check if tel contains only digits; you might wanna enhance the regular expression to restrict the tel number to have certain number of digits.
        result = re.match(r'\d+', tel)  
        if result:
            return tel  # tel is clean so return it
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Phone number contains invalid character.")
```